# How do I get the author of a JPG or PNG file in ASP (classic)?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How do I get the author of JPG or PNG file in classic ASP?

I'd like to get the information shown below from the file metadata:

[example authors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHR0.png)

Comment: Your question asks about "classic asp", but you've tagged it with "ASP.NET". Are you doing this in ASP.NET? If so, which language? (C#, F#, or VB.NET) If you're doing it in Classic ASP, confirm that you want to use VBScript to access this information?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ok thanks . I'm going to switch to vbscript

Comment: What type of image file? PNG? JPG? BMP? TIFF?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the types are PNG and JPG

Comment: I'd suggest to maybe to use a component here, like AspJpeg http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_07.html, or csImageFile https://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/exifread.asp for JPGs at least. I don't think either of these support exif from PNG files though.